List text in multiple rows
Multiple rows of text are displayed in the HotkeyEditor.
What UI components are needed to reproduce this UI?
I looked for the source hotkeyEditor.mel, but it uses "TextScrollList", and TextScrollList doesn't seem to support multiple rows.

Tbh you should consider using pyside2 treewidget, which is way better than using multiple scrolllist items. Example https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/treewidget.html, and it is way easier than generating through mel.
